# Bind list to DataGridView not displaying anything and wiping out objects every time I click save

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkedlistbox

I am trying to bind a class list to a DataGridView on my WinForms application. Currently the bind code doesn't do anything. I have debugged through it and the source is correct contains the list with the correct item. But I don't see the rows in the DataGridView.

How do I display whats in the list onto my DataGridView? Also currently every time I click save it clears my class object, however I want to keep the previous values I put in the constructor. If there is already a country that exists I want a user pop up box to state whether they want to over write this or not - is this possible/ how can I best achieve this?

CountryWithDates.cs

```
 class CountryWithDates
{
    public string country;
    public DateTime firstDate;
    public DateTime furtherDate;
    public DateTime rolldownDate;
    public DateTime endDate;
}
```

On save click:

```
  private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<CountryWithDates> countryDates = new List<CountryWithDates>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Countries_LB.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Countries_LB.GetItemChecked(i))
            {         
                countryDates.Add(new CountryWithDates(){country = Countries_LB.Items[i].ToString(),
                    firstMarkdownDate = DateTime.Parse(firstDatePicker.Text),
                    furtherMarkdownDate = DateTime.Parse(furtherDatePicker.Text),
                    rolldownMarkdownDate = DateTime.Parse(rolldownDatePicker.Text),
                    endMarkdownDate = DateTime.Parse(endMarkdownPicker.Text)});
            }

        }


//THIS DOESNT DO ANYTHING - I WANT TO BIND THE SOURCE TO THE GRIDVIEW but i dont see the output in the data gridview on the form when i click save
            var bindingList = new BindingList<CountryWithDates>(countryDates);
            var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
            gv_Countries.DataSource = source;

        }
```

Comment: Are you insistent on using this List<CountryWithDates> or would you accept suggestions to use something else?

Comment: I am open to suggestions to get this resolved. Although it would be good to know how to do it like above if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create public **Porperties** in your class and not public **Fields**:

```cs
class CountryWithDates
{
    //Following the naming rule is good. I'll leave it to you.
    public string country { get; set; }
    public DateTime firstDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime furtherDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime rolldownDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }

    public CountryWithDates() { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return country;
    }
}
```

This way you can bind a list of `CountryWithDates` objects to the `CheckedListBox`:

```cs
var lst = new List<CountryWithDates>();

//Add new objects ...
//lst.Add(new CountryWithDates { country = "Country 1", firstDate ... });

checkedListBox1.DataSource = null;
checkedListBox1.DataSource = lst;
```

To get and update the checked items from the list, create a new `BindingSource`, and bind it to the `DataGridView`, you just need to do:

```cs
checkedListBox1.CheckedItems
    .Cast<CountryWithDates>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(item =>
    {
        item.firstDate = firstDatePicker.Value;
        item.furtherDate = furtherDatePicker.Value;
        item.rolldownDate = rolldownDatePicker.Value;
        item.endDate = endMarkdownPicker.Value;
    });
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
var bs = new BindingSource(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast<CountryWithDates>(), null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: I am also adding values from date time pickers when I click save. See original code. How does this effect the answer provided? I need to add the date time picker selected item to the list for each country?

Answer (score 2):

If I were doing this I would:

- Add a new DataSet to my project
- Open the DataSet designer
- Add a DataTable, call it CountryWithDates, 6 columns (Country, First, Further, Markdown, End, SaveThisRow(boolean))
- Save the DataSet
- Open the form designer
- Show the datasources window
- Drag the node representing CountryWithDates onto the designer

DataGridView appears, as does dataset, bindingsource etc. Everything is bound already.

When time comes to save to disk and you only want to save those checked items, `datatable.Copy()` it, then delete every row that isn't marked for save, then call WriteXml to save the cleaned up copy. Perhaps something like this (untested):

```
private blah SaveButton_Click(blah){

    var dt = (CountryWithDatesDataTable)_myDataset.CountryWithDates.Copy();
    for(int i = dt.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      if(!dt[i].SaveThisRow)
        dt[i].Delete(); //mark row deleted
    }
    dt.WriteXml(@"C:\temp\dt.xml")

}
```